# UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname PDT identified but not understood. Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime

Tags: python-2.7

Can anyone help me with this issue?  I'm trying to get AWS RSS info and feed it into Zabbix.

> usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py:1204: UnknownTimezoneWarning: tzname PDT identified but not understood.  Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly return a timezone-aware datetime.  In a future version, this will raise an exception.
>    category=UnknownTimezoneWarning)

from _parser.py:

```
def _build_tzaware(self, naive, res, tzinfos):
        if (callable(tzinfos) or (tzinfos and res.tzname in tzinfos)):
            tzinfo = self._build_tzinfo(tzinfos, res.tzname, res.tzoffset)
            aware = naive.replace(tzinfo=tzinfo)
            aware = self._assign_tzname(aware, res.tzname)

        elif res.tzname and res.tzname in time.tzname:
            aware = naive.replace(tzinfo=tz.tzlocal())

            # Handle ambiguous local datetime
            aware = self._assign_tzname(aware, res.tzname)

            # This is mostly relevant for winter GMT zones parsed in the UK
            if (aware.tzname() != res.tzname and
                    res.tzname in self.info.UTCZONE):
                aware = aware.replace(tzinfo=tz.tzutc())

        elif res.tzoffset == 0:
            aware = naive.replace(tzinfo=tz.tzutc())

        elif res.tzoffset:
            aware = naive.replace(tzinfo=tz.tzoffset(res.tzname, res.tzoffset))

        elif not res.tzname and not res.tzoffset:
            # i.e. no timezone information was found.
            aware = naive

        elif res.tzname:
            # tz-like string was parsed but we don't know what to do
            # with it
            warnings.warn("tzname {tzname} identified but not understood.  "
                          "Pass `tzinfos` argument in order to correctly "
                          "return a timezone-aware datetime.
```

Full code here:https://github.com/tech-sketch/zabbix_aws_template/blob/master/scripts/AWS_Service_Health_Dashboard.py

Comment: I doubt you found a bug in the `dateutil` module so displaying this code is irrelevant. Please show us the full stack-trace and the code **you** wrote

Comment: @gogaz, posted  link to script

Comment: turned out i had CET timezone, changing it to PDT removed error